# opencv tutorial for macosx

Tags: macos, opencv

i am trying to install opencv following this tutorial but i cannot find the ~/.profile directory. its says i dont have permission and when i sudo into it it says it cant find it but when i see it. i dont know how to find it.http://thepetitegeek.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-opencv-on-mac-os-x-with.html

and when i try to execute houghline

```
 File "houghlines.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ctypes_opencv.cv import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ctypes_opencv.cxcore import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/cxcore.py", line 80, in <module>
    _cxDLL, _cvDLL, _hgDLL = detect_opencv()    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/cxcore.py", line 58, in detect_opencv
    cxDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary(find_lib('cxcore'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ctypes_opencv/cxcore.py", line 54, in find_lib
    raise ImportError("OpenCV's shared library '%s' is not found. Make sure you have its path included in your PATH variable." % name)
ImportError: OpenCV's shared library 'cxcore' is not found. Make sure you have its path included in your PATH variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

The ~/.profile "directory" may not exist.  It's a file, and you need to create it in your user directory.